# How to create a specific layout arrangement using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple block of three elements which I am showing in my app as follows
3 items on desktop devices but on small devices eg tablets and phones I want to show this element as follows

[image]

Here is my solution in file [live demo on jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wgnf510/1/)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 544px) {
  .grid-container {
    /* I tried this but the 3rd element not taking the full width */
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    3
    <h1>Grid Elements</h1>
    <p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `grid-column: span 2` rule for the third element, defining it through `:nth-child(3)`. This will stretch this element by two columns. Like this:

```
.grid-item:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 544px) {
    .grid-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    }
    .grid-item:nth-child(3) {
        grid-column: span 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        3
        <h1>Grid Elements</h1>
        <p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good article to learn about this CSS property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout

For Tablet and mobile device, we need to set media query as below

```css
        .grid-container {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr;
          background-color: #2196F3;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        .grid-item {
          background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
          border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
          padding: 20px;
          font-size: 30px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        @media (max-width: 544px){
            .grid-container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
            }
            .item {
                  grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-end: span 2;
            }
        }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
 .item {
                  grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-end: span 2;
            }
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item item">3
  
  <h1>Grid Elements</h1>

<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>

  
  </div>  

</div>
```